# Requiring unknown module "object-assign"

Tags: react-native

Hi i am a newbie to react native, just now installed react and trying to open my first app but it shows error. Please guide me what to do next and why it happens.

[image]

Comment: did  you do `npm install`?

Comment: @Cherniv yes i did it already but no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some packages you installed maybe not compatible with the React Native version you used. You can check the **peerDependencies** of all your dependencies and try to remove dependencies which have a react-native version less than 0.25 in **peerDependencies**.